# PHP Form to Database - No error, yet no result

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation

I'm trying to create an application form with PHP. I've set up the HTML markup, and created the PHP processor. To no avail, unfortunately. I am not getting any errors, but the database is not updating either. Would be very greatful if you could have a look at my code.

HTML Markup:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/new_post" id="application-form">
                        <table class="application">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 1</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="30" name="question1" id="question1"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 2</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="30" name="question2" id="question2"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 3</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="30" name="question3" id="question3"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 4</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="30" name="question4" id="question4"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 5</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="question5" id="question5"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 6</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="question6" id="question7"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 7</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="30" name="question7" id="question7"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 8</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="question8" id="question8"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 9</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="question9" id="question9"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 10</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="question10" id="question10"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 11</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="question11" id="question11"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 12</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="30" name="question12" id="question12"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 13</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="question13" id="question13"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 14</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="question14" id="question14"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Question 15</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="30" name="question15" id="question15"/></td>
                                </tr>                           
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger martop15">Send Application</button>
                    </form>
```

PHP Processor:

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $question1 = $_POST['question1']; 
        $question2 = $_POST['question2']; 
        $question3 = $_POST['question3']; 
        $question4 = $_POST['question4']; 
        $question5 = $_POST['question5']; 
        $question6 = $_POST['question6']; 
        $question7 = $_POST['question7']; 
        $question8 = $_POST['question8']; 
        $question9 = $_POST['question9']; 
        $question10 = $_POST['question10']; 
        $question11 = $_POST['question11']; 
        $question12 = $_POST['question12']; 
        $question13 = $_POST['question13']; 
        $question14 = $_POST['question14']; 
        $question15 = $_POST['question15']; 

    }

        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `applications`(`question1`, `question2`, `question3`, `question4`, `question5`, `question6`, `quesion7`, `question8`, `question9`, `question10`, `question11`, `question12`, `question13`, `question14`, `question15`) VALUES (`$question1`, `$question2`, `$question3`, `$question4`, `$question5`, `$question6`, `$question7`, `$question8`, `$question9`, `$question10`, `$question11`, `$question12`, `$question13`, `$question14`, `$question15`)");
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the ticks `\`` from your values and replace them with quotes `'`. Those are values, not columns. Had you been checking for errors, you'd of been told about it. A quick search & replace will fix that in a jiffy.

Comment: You're not seeing any errors because you're not looking for them. Add some error checking to your `mysqli_*()` calls.

Comment: You should really look into sanitizing your data as well.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection :/

Comment: Nota: You also may have mispelled the word "quesion7" for that column, something that wasn't noted anywhere, except the answer I edited to make it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
   $queryResult =  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO applications(question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6,quesion7, question8, question9, question10, question11, question12, question13, question14,question15) VALUES ('$question1', '$question2', '$question3', '$question4', '$question5', '$question6', '$question7', '$question8', '$question9', '$question10','$question11', '$question12', '$question13','$question14', '$question15')");
```

Remove ``` `` ``` from `insert into TableName (here,here)`

For error handling

```
if ($queryResult === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: ";
}
```

Comment: Not `$conn`, but `$mysqli` - since OP's using `$mysqli` for a variable. So why use `$conn`?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I've tried to implement it, but now getting "Message: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string"

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Just saw your edit - it works like a charm now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If your statement fails, you can output the error message by doing the following:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `applications`(`question1`, `question2`, `question3`, `question4`, `question5`, `question6`, `quesion7`, `question8`, `question9`, `question10`, `question11`, `question12`, `question13`, `question14`, `question15`) VALUES (`$question1`, `$question2`, `$question3`, `$question4`, `$question5`, `$question6`, `$question7`, `$question8`, `$question9`, `$question10`, `$question11`, `$question12`, `$question13`, `$question14`, `$question15`)")) {
  printf("Error message: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

For INSERT statements, `$mysqli->query` statements will return `TRUE` if the statement is successful, `FALSE` otherwise. The above should give you an indication as to what went wrong.

---

**Edit:**

You're using the incorrect [**identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for your VALUES, being ticks and should be regular single quotes instead.

Change it to:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `applications` (`question1`, `question2`, `question3`, `question4`, `question5`, `question6`, `quesion7`, `question8`, `question9`, `question10`, `question11`, `question12`, `question13`, `question14`, `question15`) VALUES ('$question1', '$question2', '$question3', '$question4', '$question5', '$question6', '$question7', '$question8', '$question9', '$question10', '$question11', '$question12', '$question13', '$question14', '$question15')")) {
  printf("Error message: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

**N.B.:**

Plus, you may have mispelled your "quesion7" column, which should most likely read as "question7".

It should be modified if that is the case, but wasn't made in the code above.

---

**Important note:**

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Sure, it will print it out, but that doesn't solve the problem and would best be said in a comment.

Comment: @fred-ii: Still wrapping my head around StackOverflow, I appreciate the advice.

Comment: You're welcome Eric. If you were to remove the ticks from the values in your answer, and replace them with quotes, then that would make it better. See the accepted answer for how they did it.

Comment: I've made an edit to your answer Eric, so just to make things right ;-)

Answer (score -1):

In your code you added quotes for database field names i think this was problem

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO applications (question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, quesion7, question8, question9, question10,question11, question12, question13, question14, question15) VALUES (`$question1`, `$question2`, `$question3`, `$question4`, `$question5`, `$question6`, `$question7`, `$question8`, `$question9`, `$question10`, `$question11`, `$question12`, `$question13`, `$question14`, `$question15`)");
```

try out this.
i have doubt in form action u passing segments by "/" seprated is there this support in core php actually we pass only query strings only in some frameworks we use "/"

Comment: If you try to use `` Tick in values, you get SQL -> INSERT INTO articles (id,a) values(<Backtick>102<Backtick>,<Backtick>test<Backtick>);  And Error `Unknown column '102' in 'field list'`  . Please modify answer.

Where <Backtick> is `